# How do I use the grouping clause in my select statement with grouping sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, grouping, hierarchy

I just learned of using the grouping sets clause and I believe I can re write one of my old queries. Currently, it is a union of 5 different groupings coming from a CTE. I understand that I should be easily able to change that into the different hierarchies they are being grouped into with grouping sets of even rollup, but I need to specify a literal at each level or grouping. I can't show you my actual code, but I have an example below.

```
select 
    b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE, b.LEVEL_FOUR, b.LEVEL_FIVE,
    case
        when (grouping(b.LEVEL_FIVE)=1) then ''
        when ...
        when ...
        when ...
        when ...
        when ...
    end as'LEVEL_TYPE',
    sum(b.VALUE) as TOTAL
from
    BASE b
where
    ...
group by GROUPING SETS(
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE, b.LEVEL_FOUR, b.LEVEL_FIVE),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE, b.LEVEL_FOUR),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_FOUR),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO)
)
```

This is only a general idea of where I think I want to go. The problem I'm having is how do I specify the literal when I use either the 3rd or 4th grouping set. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Expected results are rows that look like the following:

```
LEVEL_ONE | LEVEL_TWO | LEVEL_THREE | LEVEL_FOUR | LEVEL_FIVE | LEVEL_TYPE | TOTAL

'lvl1'    | 'lvl2'    | 'lvl3'      | 'lvl4'     | 'lvl5'     | 'LEVEL 5'  | (int)
...
'lvl1'    | 'lvl2'    | 'lvl3'      | 'lvl4'     | null       | 'LEVEL 3,4'| (int)
...
'lvl1'    | 'lvl2'    | null       | 'lvl4'     | null       | 'LEVEL 4'  | (int)
...
'lvl1'    | 'lvl2'    | 'lvl3'      | null       | null       | 'LEVEL 3'  | (int)
...
'lvl1'    | 'lvl2'    | null       | null       | null       | 'LEVEL 2'  | (int)
...
'lvl1'    | null      | null        | null       | null       | 'LEVEL 1'  | (int)
...
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)? Could you possibly provide sample data and expected results for your example?

Comment: SQL Server 2005. Sample data is not available. The fields in my instance are only ints. Expected results will be included.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question but why is the `(b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO)` item specified twice? Actually, based on your expected output, I think you've made a mistake there and the second entry should be just `(b.LEVEL_ONE)` instead.

Comment: Yes. That is what it was supposed to be, but the question has since been closed and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get more and better answers if you include SQL DDL and sample data. Code below is untested.

To better see what's going on, include a column for each grouping set.

```
select 
    b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE, b.LEVEL_FOUR, b.LEVEL_FIVE,
    grouping(LEVEL_ONE)   grp_lvl1,
    grouping(LEVEL_TWO)   grp_lvl2,
    grouping(LEVEL_THREE) grp_lvl3,
    grouping(LEVEL_FOUR)  grp_lvl4,
    grouping(LEVEL_FIVE)  grp_lvl5,
    sum(b.VALUE) as TOTAL
from
    BASE b
where
    ...
group by GROUPING SETS(
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE, b.LEVEL_FOUR, b.LEVEL_FIVE),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE, b.LEVEL_FOUR),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_THREE),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO, b.LEVEL_FOUR),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO),
    (b.LEVEL_ONE, b.LEVEL_TWO)
);
```

I'm not certain the grouping sets you *wrote* are actually the ones you *want*. Look closely at them.

Once you examine the output of that query, you'll be able to see how to structure your CASE...WHEN expression. It will probably end up looking *something* like this.

```
(case when (grouping(LEVEL_ONE)   = 1) and
           (grouping(LEVEL_TWO)   = 1) and
           (grouping(LEVEL_THREE) = 1) and 
           (grouping(LEVEL_FOUR)  = 1) and 
           (grouping(LEVEL_FIVE)  = 1) then 'Some string literal here'
      when (grouping(LEVEL_ONE)   = 0) and
           (grouping(LEVEL_TWO)   = 1) and
           (grouping(LEVEL_THREE) = 1) and 
           (grouping(LEVEL_FOUR)  = 1) and 
           (grouping(LEVEL_FIVE)  = 1) then 'Some other string literal here'
      when ...
 end) LEVEL_TYPE
```

Comment: Right. That's how I eventually ended up solving it by first studying the output of the grouping() clause and then rearranging the values for the correct combinations.